# Why use Jquery getScript() VS <script src=""></script>?

Tags: jquery, performance, optimization

Why do  some developers use getScript() instead of calling an external javascript file in HTML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main reason I can think of is so they can have programmatic control over the process, including choosing at runtime what script(s) to get, getting success/error callbacks, etc.